# How to dynamically generate pydantic base model and schema model from database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi, pydantic

i am building application and using FastApi for the API development, however, i can create (ORM base Model and Schema modal by manually defining it)

but i want a situation where this model definition comes from my database already defined there.

How to dynamically generate pydantic base model and schema model from database

i realy need help on this.

```
// at the moment my post schema is like this
class Post(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    content: str
    postdate: str


// and my ORM model is like this
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "posts"

    # Defining Colums
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False)
    content = Column(String, nullable=False)
    postdate= Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True),
                        nullable=False, server_default=text('now()'))



// what i want now is to dynamically generate the model fields from database. because it would be already created there.

example

class Post(BaseModel):
    // this should be populated here from database


// and my ORM model is like this
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "posts"

    # Defining Colums
    // this should be populated here from database
```

Comment: For SQLAlchemy models there is [sqlacodegen](https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen/). Googling for the pydantic part got me https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/